# Euler's path in Partially Directed Graph

Tags: graph

Eulerian Path is a path in graph that visits every edge exactly once.

There are many algorithms to find Eulerian path in both directed and undirected graphs. I am enthusiastic to know how to find Eulerian path in a partially directed graph.

A partially directed graph is a graph with some(not all) of its edges directed.

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: I would suggest you start reading some research papers then :)

Comment: This would fit better on Computer Science SE.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to refer some research papers.
Hope this one helps :)

[Covering partially directed graphs with directed paths](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X06001968)

Note: I would have commented this but i do not have enough reputation yet.